# multiple values not getting stored in array in php ,help me with the code below

Tags: php, html

My PHP code:

```
<?php
include 'function.php';
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","messmanagementsys");
session_start();
if(mysqli_connect_error())
{
    echo "ERROR CONNECTING TO THE DATABASE";
}
else{
    $vali=$_POST['noie'];
    echo $vali;
    for($i=1;$i<=$vali;$i++)
    {

    $iname=$_POST['ingname'.$i];
    $icode=$_POST['ingcode'.$i];
    $icur=$_POST['ingcur'.$i];
    $ireq=$_POST['ingreq'.$i];
    $icost=$_POST['ingcost'.$i];
    $idate=$_POST['ingdate'.$i];
    $check="SELECT `ingcode` FROM `ing` WHERE ingcode='$icode'";
    $s=mysqli_query($db,$check);
    $coderepeat=mysqli_fetch_array($s);
    $e=mysqli_num_rows($s);
    echo $e;
    if($e>0)
    {
        echo "<script>$(function(){
            $('#my-dialog-id').dialog();
        });
        </script>";
        if(isset($_POST['ingyes']))
        {
            $update="UPDATE `ing` SET `ingname`='$iname',`ingcode`='$icode',`current`='$icur',`required`='$ireq',`ingcost`='$icost',`date`='$idate' WHERE 1";    
        }
        if(isset($_POST['ingno'])){
            header("Refresh:0:url=ingredient.php");
        }
    }
    else{
    $query="INSERT INTO `ing`(`ingname`, `ingcode`, `current`, `required`, `ingcost`, `date`) VALUES   ('$iname','$icode','$icur','$ireq','$icost','$idate')";
    $res=mysqli_query($db,$query);


    if($res)
    header("Refresh:0;url=ingredient.php");
   else
   echo "SOMETHING WENT WRONG";

    }
}
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form action="ingupdate.php" method="POST">
<div id='my-dialog-id' title='my dialog title'>
    <p>The item <?php $string=implode(",",$coderepeat);echo $string;?> already exists do u wish to update??</p>
  <button name="ingyes" >YES</button>
  <button name="ingno">NO</button>
</div>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</body>
```

> I need to print the code which is being repeated.
>           I have put the entries in an array in php but if i have 2 codes which are repetitive then the array has he same value stored twice. 
>           I'm getting the values of the variable from a html page and the user selects the no of entries he wants to make.
>           I'm creating the input field dynamically and setting names dynamically so I'm retrieving them in PHP by concatenating `ingname` with `$i` which is a variable which is set to the no of input fields user has requested. 
>          I'm using loops and retrieving the values of those input fields.
>           What can i do to enter into array the 2 values?
>           Here is my html code:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    `<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee Shade' rel='stylesheet'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Eater' rel='stylesheet'>
        <title>Ingredients Details</title>
    <style>

    table {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }

    td, th {
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 8px;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #dddddd;
    }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
          <center> <h1 id="labelb">Ingredients Details</h1></center> 




    <form action="ingupdate.php" method="POST" >
    <input type="text" name="noie" placeholder="Enter the no of ingredients to add" style="width:200px;" id="noie"> 
          <button id="noieb">Enter</button>
    <table id="ingredients">
      <thead><tr>
        <th>Ingredient name:</th>
        <th>Ingredient code:</th>
        <th>Current<sub>(in stock in kgs)</sub></th>
        <th>Required<sub>(excluding stocks in kgs)</sub></th>
        <th>Cost<sub>(in Rupees including transportation)</sub></th>
        <th>Date:</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="ing">
    <?php
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","messmanagementsys");
    session_start();
    if(mysqli_connect_error())
    {
        echo "ERROR CONNECTING TO THE DATABASE";
    }
    else{
    //$query1="SELECT * FROM login ";
    $usr=$_SESSION['adminuser'];
    $query1="SELECT * FROM `ing` WHERE 1";
    $result1=mysqli_query($db,$query1);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
        {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>"; 
          echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row[5] . "</td>";



          echo "</tr>";
        } 
      }
      //echo "<td><form action='fineedit.php' method='POST'><select name='sfstat'><option value='paid' >Paid</option><option value='unpaid' selected>No</option></select><button type='submit' name='submit'>submit</button></form></td>";

        ?>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" >SUBMIT</button>

    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      document.getElementById("noieb").onclick=function()
      {
        var i=document.getElementById("noie").value;
      for(var j=1;j<=i;j++)
      {

          var table = document.getElementById("ing");
         var row = table.insertRow(-1);
          var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
          var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
          var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
          var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
          var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
          var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);

    var name='ingname'+j;
    var code='ingcode'+j;
    var cur='ingcur'+j;
    var req='ingreq'+j;
    var cost='ingcost'+j;
    var date='ingdate'+j;
    var iname = document.createElement('input');
        iname.setAttribute("type", "text");
        iname.name = "ingname" + j;    
        iname.setAttribute("required", "true");
        cell1.appendChild(iname);
        var icode = document.createElement('input');
        icode.setAttribute("type", "text");
        icode.name = "ingcode" + j;    
        icode.setAttribute("required", "true");
        cell2.appendChild(icode);
        var icur = document.createElement('input');
        icur.setAttribute("type", "number");
        icur.name = "ingcur" + j;      
        icur.setAttribute("required", "true");
        cell3.appendChild(icur);
        var ireq = document.createElement('input');
        ireq.setAttribute("type", "number");
        ireq.name = "ingreq" + j;      
        ireq.setAttribute("required", "true");
        cell4.appendChild(ireq);
        var icost = document.createElement('input');
        icost.setAttribute("type", "number");
        icost.name = "ingcost" + j;     
        icost.setAttribute("required", "true");
        cell5.appendChild(icost);
        var idate = document.createElement('input');
        idate.setAttribute("type", "date");
        idate.name = "ingdate" + j;     
        idate.setAttribute("required", "true");
        cell6.appendChild(idate);
      }
      }

        function delrow(){
          var table = document.getElementById("ing");
          table.deleteRow(-1);

        }   
          $(document).ready(function(){
              $("input[name=edit]").on("click",function(){
                      $(".en").css("display","block");
              })
              $("input[name=save]").on("click",function(){

                  $(".en").css("display","none");
              }) 
          })
         </script>

    </body>\
```

> Second html file

```
    </html>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <head></head>
        <body>

            <form action="ingupdate.php" method="POST" >
                <input type="text" name="noie" placeholder="Enter the no of ingredients to add" style="width:200px;" id="noie"> 
                <button id="noieb">Enter</button>`

                <div id='my-dialog-id' title='my dialog title'>
                    <p>The item <?php print_r($coderepeat);?> already exists do u wish to update??</p>
                    <button name="ingyes" >YES</button>
                    <button name="ingno">NO</button>
                </div>

            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        </body>
```

Comment: where is `$_POST['ingcodeX']` coming from? Where is `$i` coming from? To me it's very unclear what you are doing here.

Comment: Sorry it's not clear what the problem is. Can you give an example of what you mean, including an example of the data values involved?

Comment: iam getting the values of the variable from a html page and the user selects the no of entries he wants to make .iam creating the input field dynamically and setting names dynamically so iam retrieving them in php by concatenating 'ingname' with $i which is a variable which is set to the no of input fields user has requested .iam using loops and retrieving  the values of those input fiels.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. Parameterize. Without a `where` clause on the `update` all rows will be updated. Is that intended? Do you mean you are getting an associative index and numeric or something else? Should you be getting multiple rows?

Comment: yeah iam not concerned about security now.iam just trying out things

Comment: Your update didn't really answer all questions. Where do you define `$i`? _"I'm using loops"_- Where? Please show us _all_ the relevant code. Also, using prepared statements isn't just about security. If someone would post data that, for example, includes a `'` or end with a back slash, your query would break. Using prepared statements would completely solve that issue.

Comment: Where's the `</form>`? And where are the `ingcode` inputs?